# The virtual machine 'vm name here' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1

Tags: virtualbox

I have been running phpVirtualBox 4.3-1 -/- VirtualBox 4.3.x compatible in a Jail on my FreeNAS 9.10 server for a number of months.

Lately I can't start my Windows2012 virtual machine.  It returns this error:[image: VirtualBox Error]

When I click on the Details link, I get the following, but can't make any sense of what it is telling me.  Please help.

```
> Exception Object (
>     [message:protected] => The virtual machine 'Server2012a' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1
>     [string:Exception:private] => 
>     [code:protected] => 0
>     [file:protected] => /usr/local/www/phpvirtualbox/lib/vboxconnector.php
>     [line:protected] => 3208
>     [trace:Exception:private] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => Array
>                 (
>                     [file] => /usr/local/www/phpvirtualbox/lib/vboxconnector.php
>                     [line] => 928
>                     [function] => remote_machineSetState
>                     [class] => vboxconnector
>                     [type] => ->
>                     [args] => Array
>                         (
>                             [0] => Array
>                                 (
>                                     [vm] => 9353d0ad-6959-4a06-8a3b-7fba73ab6019
>                                     [state] => powerUp
>                                     [fn] => machineSetState
>                                 )
> 
>                         )
> 
>                 )
> 
>             [1] => Array
>                 (
>                     [file] => /usr/local/www/phpvirtualbox/lib/ajax.php
>                     [line] => 309
>                     [function] => __call
>                     [class] => vboxconnector
>                     [type] => ->
>                     [args] => Array
>                         (
>                             [0] => machineSetState
>                             [1] => Array
>                                 (
>                                     [0] => Array
>                                         (
>                                             [vm] => 9353d0ad-6959-4a06-8a3b-7fba73ab6019
>                                             [state] => powerUp
>                                             [fn] => machineSetState
>                                         )
> 
>                                     [1] => Array
>                                         (
>                                             [0] => Array
>                                                 (
>                                                     [data] => Array
>                                                         (
>                                                             [responseData] => 
>                                                             [success] => 
>                                                             [key] => 53474945cfd7ac0bf8114767c209c2a6
>                                                         )
> 
>                                                     [errors] => Array
>                                                         (
>                                                         )
> 
>                                                     [persist] => Array
>                                                         (
>                                                         )
> 
>                                                     [messages] => Array
>                                                         (
>                                                         )
> 
>                                                 )
> 
>                                         )
> 
>                                 )
> 
>                         )
> 
>                 )
> 
>             [2] => Array
>                 (
>                     [file] => /usr/local/www/phpvirtualbox/lib/ajax.php
>                     [line] => 309
>                     [function] => machineSetState
>                     [class] => vboxconnector
>                     [type] => ->
>                     [args] => Array
>                         (
>                             [0] => Array
>                                 (
>                                     [vm] => 9353d0ad-6959-4a06-8a3b-7fba73ab6019
>                                     [state] => powerUp
>                                     [fn] => machineSetState
>                                 )
> 
>                             [1] => Array
>                                 (
>                                     [0] => Array
>                                         (
>                                             [data] => Array
>                                                 (
>                                                     [responseData] => 
>                                                     [success] => 
>                                                     [key] => 53474945cfd7ac0bf8114767c209c2a6
>                                                 )
> 
>                                             [errors] => Array
>                                                 (
>                                                 )
> 
>                                             [persist] => Array
>                                                 (
>                                                 )
> 
>                                             [messages] => Array
>                                                 (
>                                                 )
> 
>                                         )
> 
>                                 )
> 
>                         )
> 
>                 )
> 
>         )
> 
>     [previous:Exception:private] =>  )
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was worried that there was a problem with my VM, but I suspect the problem may be with VirtualBox itself, because when I create a fresh new VM, and try to start it, I get the same error.

Comment: Could you post VirtualBox logs? The output you posted is just the call to VirtualBox, but doesn't say anything about the source of the error.

Comment: Thought as much...I barely know my way around that jail.  Could you perhaps tell me where I will find these log files you speak of?